# pymongo.MongoClient being created instead of mongomock.MongoClient

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, pymongo, mongomock

When I tried to run my test it tries to create a real conection with MongoDB instead of using mongomock.

This stop happening when I remove the "from .main import HashClient" from my **init**.py.

my project is:

hash_controller/

|

|----> **init**.py

|----> hash_controller.py

|----> test_hash_controller.py

My **init**.py is:

```
`from .main import HashClient`
```

My hash_controller is:

```
    import hashlib
    import json
    import os
    import time


    def get_connection():
        _db_user = os.environ["HASH_DB_USER"]
        _db_password = os.environ["HASH_DB_PASS"]
        _db_host = os.environ["HASH_DB_HOST"]
        _db_port = os.environ["HASH_DB_PORT"]
        _db_name = os.environ["HASH_DB_NAME"]
        _db_collection = os.environ["HASH_DB_COLLECTION"]

        # _client = MongoClient(f"mongodb://{_db_user}:{_db_password}@{_db_host}:{_db_port}/")
        from pymongo import MongoClient
        _client = MongoClient(f"mongodb://{_db_host}:{_db_port}/")
        _database = _client[_db_name]
        _collection = _database[_db_collection]
        return _collection


    class HashClient:

        @staticmethod
        def exist(customer_uuid: str, type: str, obj):
            HashClient._check_customer_and_type(customer_uuid, type)
            HashClient._check_obj(obj)
            id = HashClient._get_hash(customer_uuid, type, obj)
            collection = get_connection()
            item = collection.find_one(id)
            if item is None:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

and my test is:

```
    import os
    import mongomock

    os.environ["HASH_DB_USER"]=""
    os.environ["HASH_DB_PASS"]=""
    os.environ["HASH_DB_HOST"]="localhost"
    os.environ["HASH_DB_PORT"]="27017"
    os.environ["HASH_DB_NAME"]="test"
    os.environ["HASH_DB_COLLECTION"]="test"

    with mongomock.patch(servers=(('localhost', 27017),)):
        import pymongo
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost")
        from .main import HashClient


    def test_exist_false():
        hash = HashClient._get_hash("123", "user", {"user": "222"})
        client["test"]["test"].insert_one({"_id": hash})
        response = HashClient.exist("123", "user", {"user": "123"})
        assert response == False
        client.test.test.delete_many({})
```

I tried moving all the imports inside the function so they don't get executed when running the test, but anything helps.
The idea is to run the test with the import from the **init**.py

Answer (score 0):

In the last test function `def test_exist_false()`, mocked mongo `client` which is created in the `whit` block is called to save data.

`client["test"]["test"].insert_one({"_id": hash})`

It is mocked client, no problem. but `HashClient.exist()` does not use it, it even has no access to the mocked `client`.

Why `HashClient.exist()` has not access to mocked `client`?

because it creates collection itself inside itself. the problem is that the collection which is created in `exist()` function is not mocked, it's the real collection.

Better to split the file `hash_controller.py` to two files. a file for `get_collection()` and another one for `class HashClient`.

`HashClient` can set collection in method `__init__()` or `set_collection()` or etc.

So it will be possible to set the mocked collection for `HashClient` in tests.

**Edit**:

setting mock db config in `os.environ` should work too. Because the function `get_collection()` uses the config after setting it in the test file, I've no idea about imports and about why it doesn't work.

But at least to split `hash_controller.py` can increase software cohesion and independence of tests.